# MVC Controller parameter for a form element with a dot in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

If you're using the `Html.TextBoxFor()` type methods, you may well end up with Form controls that have dots in their names, like this:

`<input type="text" name="Contact.FirstName" id="Contact_FirstName" />`

If you want MVC to map those named fields to parameters in your controller (as opposed to an object parameter or whatever), you have to get the parameter names right. What to do about the dots?

Neither this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction(string firstName)
```

not this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction(string contact_FirstName)
```

seem to work.

Edit: Having a suitable object parameter would work (eg [see clicktricity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851371/mvc-controller-parameter-for-a-form-element-with-a-dot-in-it/3851512#3851512)), but I'm looking for a way to do it with named value parameters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found another way, a kind of hack because I believe this is misuse of [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx), to associate *firstName* parameter with *Contact.FirstName* input element:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction([Bind(Prefix="Contact.FirstName")]string firstName)
```

This for sure works with ASP.NET MVC 1.

Comment: Hey, thats interesting. Why do you call it a misuse? Isn't this what BindAttribute is for?

Comment: It seems BindAttribute.Prefix property was intended only to give an alias to instance of complex type.

Comment: It works on MVC 2 too. I'd call this 'creative' rather than a hack.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the other form controls, you should be able to have the MVC default model binder construct a Contact object for you.  Then the signature of your action method would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction(Contact contact)
```

Then the Contact.FirstName (and any other fileds) will be bound correctly

Comment: Thanks, yes, that would work but I'm interested if the string parameter method can also work.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  This is one of the problems with "convention over configuration" when you don't want to follow the convention.  If you need to bind to the individual value, either write a custom model binder, or fetch the value from the Forms collection

Comment: Ah, ok. So its not possible with string parameters. Thanks

Comment: Turns out there is a way to do it, with BindAttribute, see Alex P's answer.

Answer (score 4):

As Clicktricity suggests in comments you may use

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction(FormCollection form)
{
    firstName = form["Contact.FirstName"];
}
```