# Unable to remove user external login

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've trying the MVC 5.2 template with individual account. Everything works except when I trying to remove the user's login that I get the following error message:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

on the following line of ManagerController:

```
var result = await this.UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
```

This is the complete RemoveLogin action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("RemoveLogin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveLogin(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
    {
        ManageMessageId? message;
        var result = await this.UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
        if( result.Succeeded )
        {
            var user = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if( user != null )
                await this.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
        }
        else
            message = ManageMessageId.Error;

        return this.RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = message });
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem: The loginProvider and providerKey are both null.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by changing the line:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveLogin(
    string loginProvider, 
    string providerKey)
```

to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveLogin(
    [Bind(Prefix = "Account.LoginProvider")]string loginProvider,
    [Bind(Prefix = "Account.ProviderKey")]string providerKey)
```

**Cause:**

For whatever reason, the MVC binding was not resolving the parameter binding correctly:

```
<input asp-for="@account.LoginProvider" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="@account.ProviderKey" type="hidden" />
```

Was creating the following form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="account_LoginProvider" name="account.LoginProvider" value="Facebook">
<input type="hidden" id="account_ProviderKey" name="account.ProviderKey" value="...">
```

These names were not binding to the parameter names loginProvider and providerKey.

Here is the answer that provided the workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869512/567524